# I have an error in my code that does not allow me to show the results and/or show an error message in php

Tags: php, html, css, sql, date

I have a little problem that might be syntax (since I'm not that good at php). Basically, I'm de-wrapping a code where there will be records where there will be a date (in this case, a foundation date, for example; 20-08-2027). So I created an "if". If there are records with the date, for example, 2027, the records appear. If there is not, then an error message will be displayed saying that there is still no record made with that date. I've tried a few things, but nothing worked. At this point, an error appears. Below will be the error. Please try to help me. It's no use saying more technical things, because I'm not that good at php. Thank you.

Error: **"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /home/host/public_html/template/year/2027.php on line 300"**

**2027.php**

```
  <section class="content products">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="hidden">Eventos</h1>
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    
                    <div class="row grid" id="products">
                        
                       <div class="releated-products">
                
                <div class="row grid" id="products">
                    
                    <?php
                
                $sqli=sprintf("SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE YEAR(data) = 2027");
                $resu=mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
                mysqli_set_charset($con, 'UTF8');
                    
                if (mysqli_num_rows($resu)>0) {
                    while($regi=mysqli_fetch_array($resu)){
                    $sqli_consulta=sprintf("select * from eventos where id=%d;",$regi['id']);
                    $resu_consulta=mysqli_query($con,$sqli_consulta);
                   
                    $regi_consulta=mysqli_fetch_array($resu_consulta);
                    $linkk='../eventoindividual.php?id='.$regi_consulta['id'];
                    ?>
                
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <article class="product-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="product-overlay">
                                        <div class="product-mask"></div>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $linkk; ?>" class="product-permalink"></a>
                                        <img src="<?php echo '../admin/documentos/'.$regi['nome_doc']; ?>" style="width:100%">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <div class="product-body">
                                        <h3><?php echo $regi['nome']; ?></h3>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="price">
                                            <ins><span class="amount"><?php echo $regi['preco']; ?></span></ins>
                                        </span>
                                        
                                        <div class="buttons buttons-simple">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $regi['linkbilheteira']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Comprar bilhetes</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
    
                    <?php
                 } else{
                        ?>
                    <p>Nada!</p>
                    <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
                    
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error because you have `while` loop in your `if` block that you are not closing.

Check the code below for this fixed version.

```
<?php           
    $sqli=sprintf("SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE YEAR(data) = 2027");
    $resu=mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'UTF8');
        
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resu)>0):
        while($regi=mysqli_fetch_array($resu)):
        $sqli_consulta=sprintf("select * from eventos where id=%d;",$regi['id']);
        $resu_consulta=mysqli_query($con,$sqli_consulta);
        
        $regi_consulta=mysqli_fetch_array($resu_consulta);
        $linkk='../eventoindividual.php?id='.$regi_consulta['id'];
        ?>
    
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <article class="product-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="product-overlay">
                            <div class="product-mask"></div>
                            <a href="<?php echo $linkk; ?>" class="product-permalink"></a>
                            <img src="<?php echo '../admin/documentos/'.$regi['nome_doc']; ?>" style="width:100%">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="product-body">
                            <h3><?php echo $regi['nome']; ?></h3>
                            <br>
                            <span class="price">
                                <ins><span class="amount"><?php echo $regi['preco']; ?></span></ins>
                            </span>
                            
                            <div class="buttons buttons-simple">
                                <a href="<?php echo $regi['linkbilheteira']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Comprar bilhetes</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p>Nada!</p>
<?php 
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the last `}` bracket above `}else{`

```
 <section class="content products">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="hidden">Eventos</h1>
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    
                    <div class="row grid" id="products">
                        
                       <div class="releated-products">
                
                <div class="row grid" id="products">
                    
                    <?php
                
                $sqli=sprintf("SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE YEAR(data) = 2027");
                $resu=mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
                mysqli_set_charset($con, 'UTF8');
                    
                if (mysqli_num_rows($resu)>0) {
                    while($regi=mysqli_fetch_array($resu)){
                    $sqli_consulta=sprintf("select * from eventos where id=%d;",$regi['id']);
                    $resu_consulta=mysqli_query($con,$sqli_consulta);
                   
                    $regi_consulta=mysqli_fetch_array($resu_consulta);
                    $linkk='../eventoindividual.php?id='.$regi_consulta['id'];
                    ?>
                
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <article class="product-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="product-overlay">
                                        <div class="product-mask"></div>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $linkk; ?>" class="product-permalink"></a>
                                        <img src="<?php echo '../admin/documentos/'.$regi['nome_doc']; ?>" style="width:100%">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <div class="product-body">
                                        <h3><?php echo $regi['nome']; ?></h3>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="price">
                                            <ins><span class="amount"><?php echo $regi['preco']; ?></span></ins>
                                        </span>
                                        
                                        <div class="buttons buttons-simple">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $regi['linkbilheteira']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Comprar bilhetes</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
    
                    <?php
                    } // while()
                 } else{
                        ?>
                    <p>Nada!</p>
                    <?php
                    }
//                } //wrong bracket
            ?>
                    
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        
    </section>
```

For your own sanity it is a good idea leave a comment after closing bracket of a long code, so you know which block it belongs to.

Comment: Yes!!! That's what I'm saying! Thank you very much friend! Big Hug!

Answer (score 0):

Compiler can't be wrong, if it says there's syntax error then there is. The bracket before the `else` is closing the while loop - hence `else` cannot be used there, close the if condition. Here's the corrected code:

```
 <section class="content products">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="hidden">Eventos</h1>
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    
                    <div class="row grid" id="products">
                        
                       <div class="releated-products">
                
                <div class="row grid" id="products">
                    
            <?php
                
                $sqli=sprintf("SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE YEAR(data) = 2027");
                $resu=mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
                mysqli_set_charset($con, 'UTF8');
                    
                if (mysqli_num_rows($resu)>0) {
                    while($regi=mysqli_fetch_array($resu))  {
                    $sqli_consulta=sprintf("select * from eventos where id=%d;",$regi['id']);
                    $resu_consulta=mysqli_query($con,$sqli_consulta);
                   
                    $regi_consulta=mysqli_fetch_array($resu_consulta);
                    $linkk='../eventoindividual.php?id='.$regi_consulta['id'];
            /* 2 brackets { */        
            ?> 
                
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <article class="product-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="product-overlay">
                                        <div class="product-mask"></div>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $linkk; ?>" class="product-permalink"></a>
                                        <img src="<?php echo '../admin/documentos/'.$regi['nome_doc']; ?>" style="width:100%">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <div class="product-body">
                                        <h3><?php echo $regi['nome']; ?></h3>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="price">
                                            <ins><span class="amount"><?php echo $regi['preco']; ?></span></ins>
                                        </span>
                                        
                                        <div class="buttons buttons-simple">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $regi['linkbilheteira']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Comprar bilhetes</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
    
                    <?php
                 }  //  while loop
                }   //  if condition
                else {
                        ?>
                    <p>Nada!</p>
                    <?php
                }
                
            ?>
                    
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        
    </section>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Yes!!! That's what I'm saying! Thank you very much friend! Big Hug!